# Is it possible to make tkinter frame from object in list?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm trying to make a simple budget application. I'm a complete beginner in class, so I'm sorry for the structure of the program. Whenever classmethod newstuff is called I want to add a category name to the list and make frame from the name of category. Thank you for advice

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os
root = tk.Tk()
list  = []
i = 0

class Budget:
    budgAdd = 0
    transferr = 50


    def __init__(self, category, budg):
        self.category = category
        self.budg = budg

    def showBudget(self):

        #label = tk.Label(list[], text = "Ur budget for {} is {}".format(self.category, self.budg))
        #label.pack()
        return "Ur budget for {} is {}".format(self.category, self.budg)



    def adding(self):
        self.budgAdd = int(input("How mutch:"))
        self.budg = int(self.budg + self.budgAdd)

    def transfer(self, to):
        self.transferr = int(input("How mutch: "))
        self.to = to
        self.budg= int(self.budg + self.transferr)
        to.budg = int(to.budg - self.transferr)

    @classmethod
    def newstuff(self, z):

        category, budg = z.split("-")
        list.append(Budget(category,budg))

        for i in list:
            i = tk.Frame(root, bg="#18ca89")
            i.place(relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.3, relx=0.01, rely=0.01)
            i.pack()




        return Budget(category, budg)





canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = 600, width = 600, bg="#245bd1")
canvas.pack()
Budget.newstuff(input("category and budget: "))
print(list[0].category)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't get the program is supposed to do. Why does it create an empty frame? Also why are you calling `i.place(...)` then `i.pack()`? You should mix geometry managers. Also you know that you are creating 2 `Budget` objects each time `newstuff` is called.

Comment: It has to create a frame that will be named after the category name. And the frame is still empty, but I didn't put any code there that will add the name of the category to the frame where I will have buttons such as show the budget for this category, etc. So each frame will represent a different category, so far it's just a test of how it could work, so it's empty

Comment: I suggest creating a class that will deal with categories